# Radio button in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Tried looking for solutions but I have a different problem and couldn't find anything related to it
I've created a django form with fields from models.py

forms.py

```
from .models import ProValue
from django import forms


class SchoolInput(forms.ModelForm):
    school_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'input'
            }
        ))
    level_of_grades = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, required=True)
    num_of_days = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=7, required=True)
    division_check = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Do you have multiple divisions for your grades?', widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = ProValue
        answer = (
            ('no', 'no'),
            ('yes', 'yes')
        )
        fields = [
            'school_name',
            'level_of_grades',
            'num_of_days',
            'division_check',
        ]
```

With this I can't see radio buttons on the page
I've tried doing

```
    division_check = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Do you have multiple divisions for your grades?', widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

and

```
    division_check = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Do you have multiple divisions for your grades?', widget=forms.RadioSelect(choice=answer))
```

This tells me answer is not defined

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms


class ProValue(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level_of_grades = models.IntegerField()
    num_of_days = models.IntegerField()
    answer = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
    )
    division_check = models.CharField(
        max_length=5, choices=answer)
```

Plus do I need to define answer in class Meta again? I didn't do it at first, I tried to solve above problems but still couldn't with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the `answer`s in your `Meta` class, but that is not in scope when you define the widget.

You can make a reference to the options in your model, like:

```
from .models import ProValue
from django import forms


class SchoolInput(forms.ModelForm):
    school_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'input'
            }
    ))
    level_of_grades = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, required=True)
    num_of_days = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=7, required=True)
    division_check = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Do you have multiple divisions for your grades?',
        choices=ProValue.answer,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ProValue
        fields = [
            'school_name',
            'level_of_grades',
            'num_of_days',
            'division_check',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is fine, you can remove the custom field `division_check` from your form and just change the widget and label in the form's `Meta`

```
class Meta:
    model = ProValue
    fields = [
        'school_name',
        'level_of_grades',
        'num_of_days',
        'division_check',
    ]
    widgets = {
        'division_check': forms.RadioSelect,
    }
    labels = {
        'division_check': 'Do you have multiple divisions for your grades?',
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help.